# Use serial port in Python without installing external packages

Tags: python, pyserial

I have following code:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('com4',115200,timeout=1)
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
    print ser.readline()
```

I do not want to use serial module and allowed to use only standard python modules in my code.

Any quick suggestion how can I do that?

Comment: You use only python code. How else do you think to access the serial port? I assume, writing own library is beyond your capabilities. There is nothing wrong in using the module ``serial`` as well as in using the module ``time``. They are there to be used.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is that I have many computers where "pyserial" is not installed and I do not have access to install "pyserial" in those PCs. So, I need a quick alternative solution. Well, you are right that writing my own library is beyond my capabilities. It is possible but takes a lot of time which I do not have at the moment. Is not there any alternative way or python code to do that? Or am I being just to optimistic? :)

Comment: since `pyserial` is a python-only implementation, you could just add it to your project; no need to *install* it (to your system directories)

Comment: So you have access to the serial port on those computers, but don't have access to do `python setup.py install --user`?

Comment: @TheBlackCat On that particular PC I have access for both,..but there are others PCs where I do not have access...that's why I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pyserial is written in pure python; you can copy the [`serial`](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/pyserial/code/trunk/pyserial/serial/)  folder into your project as a package, and it would work without installing anything.

Alternatively you can see its source code on how to implement similar functionality on your platform (Win32?) without including the whole library.

Comment: Happala : Yes, my platform is win32, I like your second option and will work on implementing similar functionality,Thank you!